# Get calendar entries OL 2010 VS 2015

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm a little confused on how to approach this as the wealth of information out there is putting me on different paths.

What I'm trying to do is create an Outlook plugin (for OL 2010) using **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition** which will read all calendar entries (the account is not on an Exchange server).

I read this article but decided to ignore it [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310259][1] because it was targeting OL 2003.

After reading a few other articles they all seem to be using Interop which makes me think that Microsoft would have probably updated a task such as this probably with other libraries.

So i decided to give CalendarView a go

```
 Outlook.CalendarView vw = new Outlook.CalendarView();
```

and got an error

> *Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).*

So should i be using Interop (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`) in order to get the current calendar's entries along with title, location, time, date etc etc? Or is there a modern approach with Visual Studio 2015?

I just didnt want to register assemblies on PCs once the plugin is ready if there is a better approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CalendarView object is not creatable, it can only be retrieved from other Outlook Object Model objects.

That being said, CalendarView is just that - a view. It cannot be used to retrieve data.

Call `Aplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)` to open the default Calendar folder, then iterate through its items using the `MAPIFolder.Items` collection.